# Why does FFMPEG showinfo filter output less timestamps than frames

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I am using FFMPEG to extract timestamps of every frame of a video. The command I use is: `ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -an -vf showinfo frames\%04d.jpg 2> log.txt`. Then I parse the output file to extract timestamps.

The problem is that I found for some videos the number of timestamps is less than the number of frames. Some content in the log file:

```
...
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 000001c68efd5d40] n:   0 pts:      0 pts_time:0       pos:   744736 fmt:yuvj420p sar:1/1 s:1920x1080 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:C086C8AD plane_checksum:[967F2494 DE1FDB06 FA11C904] mean:[97 125 129 ] stdev:[48.3 8.0 6.7 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 000001c68efd5d40] color_range:pc color_space:bt709 color_primaries:bt709 color_trc:bt709
...
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 000001c68efd5d40] n:9003 pts: 300793 pts_time:300.493 pos:248599172 fmt:yuvj420p sar:1/1 s:1920x1080 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:2A3F467C plane_checksum:[B8AFA4CB 96D8FC10 1EE5A583] mean:[99 130 126 ] stdev:[44.4 9.3 6.0 ]
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 000001c68efd5d40] color_range:pc color_space:bt709 color_primaries:bt709 color_trc:bt709
frame= 9007 fps= 32 q=24.8 Lsize=N/A time=00:05:00.53 bitrate=N/A dup=3 drop=0 speed=1.05x    
video:633532kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

I get 9007 frames but only 9004 timestamps. The timestamp of the first and the last frame seem quite normal that there should be no frames missing at the beginning or the end the video. So I'd like to know the reason and which 9004 out of the 9007 frames have their timestamps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The image sequence writer in ffmpeg defaults to constant frame rate output where the target rate is the same as the input frame rate unless manually set otherwise.

Your input appears to have a few gaps and ffmpeg has duplicated frames to maintain a constant frame rate. See `dup=3 drop=0` in the final status line.

Add `-vsync 0` to prevent this duplication.

Comment: I got video decoding failed `[mjpeg @ 0000015d22980540] Invalid pts (1594) <= last (1594)` in the midway after I added `-vsync 0`.

Comment: Got 9004 frames, 9004 timestamps and no errors when I tried `-vsync 2`. Could you help explain a little bit more on the different results?

Comment: The JPEG encoder seems to require distinct timestamps. For that you can use `-vf setpts=N -vsync 0`. With `-vsync 2`, frames can be dropped so avoid that.

Comment: I checked `-vf setpts=N` but what I want is the real timestamps. With `-vsync 2` there would less frames than it actually has. I hope to get all the frames with corresponding time stamps, even timestamps are duplicated.

Comment: ffmpeg will not allow non-monotonic timestamps to be outputted. And the specific encoder you're using (jpeg) requires distinct TS per frame. You can always insert showinfo before the setpts to record original timestamps.

Comment: Sorry for the quite late reply. I tried extracting frame by frame using the C API of FFMPEG and got also 9004 (less) frames. I guess that the video itself does not have duplicated timestamps. It is the JPEG encoder which is asking to decoder to duplicate some frames.